# добавление CSRF-токена в заголовок запроса

Tags: php, csrf

Добрый день, раньше к crm (bpmonline) по протоколу OData выполняли запросы таким образом:

```
$url = "https://0632.bpmonline.com/ServiceModel/AuthService.svc/Login";
$requestData["Language"] = "ru";
$requestData["SolutionName"] = "TSBpm";
$requestData["TimeZoneOffset"] = -180;
$requestData["UserName"] = "user";
$requestData["UserPassword"] = "pass";
$jcres = json_encode($requestData);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jcres);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jcres))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$url = "https://0632.bpmonline.com/0/ServiceModel/EntityDataService.svc/LeadCollection";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

$obj = new stdClass();
$arr = array(
    "LeadName" => 'name',
    'Email' => 'test@gmail.com',
);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $obj->{$k} = $v;
}
$json = json_encode($obj);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Вчера была обновлена версия crm и добавлена защита от CSRF атак и теперь не удается выполнять запросы, появляется ошибка: `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.`
Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно реализовать добавление CSRF-токена в заголовок запроса.

Comment: токен в заголовках не посылается,а посылается ка все остальные POST параметры.И если на сайте проверяется его наличие то вы никак не можете его генерировать.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan в зависимости от сайта иногда допустимо и в заголовках тоже (обычно `X-CSRFToken`)

Comment: Через заголовки ПЕРЕДАЕТСЯ токен, пример - Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь, получилось реализовать с помощью получения CSRFT токена из cookie.txt и добавления в заголовок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$token = $doc->getElementById("signin__csrf_token")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jcres)),
    'X-CSRF-Token:' .  $token;
);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785578/curl-csrf-token